# Tailwind not being applied to library

Tags: tailwind-css

I have created a library in angular which is styled using tailwind. This is then been push to NPM and then imported into a new project, but the css is not getting applied. I have referenced the node-module path in my tailwind.config.ts:

```
    content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
    './node_modules/components-name/**/*.{html,js,ts}'
  ],
```

What am i missing?

Tailwind is working if i apply it directly to the new application, it just doesn't work with the imported library.

Comment: I think this will help you fix your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70937474/18624880

Answer (score 4):

If you expect all depender apps to utilize tailwind, you can use tailwind classes in your library HTML and have them configure a `content` path of `./node_modules/my-lib/esm2020/**/*.mjs`.
It finds the inlined/escaped classes in the Ivy compiled files.
`esm2020` to scope the scan.

---

#### Update 11/30/22 - allowing the use of `@apply` in the library

`@apply`s are not resolved in precompiled library code as these files are not processed in that lifecycle.
As a workaround, you can pre-process your components to resolve `@apply` styles before building the library.

1. Create a `tailwind.config.js` to use in the compilation

   - If your library project has a demo-app (highly suggest for impl testing), could utilize it's config file, unless you've got some crazy config in there. Since we're not rendering `@tailwind components` or anything, we won't get any excess styles

**`projects/my-lib/tailwind.config.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './projects/my-lib/**/*.{html,ts,css,scss}',
  ],
};
```

> Note the `content` path is still relative from project root as that's the context it's ran at

2. Create precompiler process

   - Tailwind resolve into a new file (mostly so we don't mess things up accidentally locally)
   - Point component at the new file

```js
import { readFile, writeFile } from "fs";
import { sync } from 'glob';
import { exec } from 'child_process';

const libRoot      = 'projects/my-lib/src/lib';
const tailwindConf = 'tailwind.config.js'; // may be apps/demo when using NX
const processedExt = '.precompiled.scss';
const styleRegex   = /styleUrls:\s*\[([^\]]+)]/;

// Find all `.scss` files and tailwind process them
sync(`${libRoot}/**/*.component.scss`).forEach(file => {
  const cssFile = file.replace(/\.scss$/, processedExt);
  exec(`npx tailwind -c ${tailwindConf} -i ${file} -o ${cssFile}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(stderr);
      throw err;
    }
  });
});

// .component.ts update
// Find all components with `styleUrls` and switch `.scss` extension to our precompiled file names
sync(`${libRoot}/**/*.component.ts`).forEach(file => {
  readFile(file, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const content = data.toString();
    const match = content.match(styleRegex);
    if (match) {
      const styleUrls = match[1]
        .split(',')
        .map(s => s.trim().replace('.scss', processedExt))
        .join(', ');

      writeFile(file, content.replace(styleRegex, `styleUrls: [${styleUrls}]`), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

> This should only be ran by your CI process and never committed.
> Also this could easily be switched to javascript instead of typescript

Other possible ways to do this (untested) without the `.component.ts` update:

- Utilize `environment.prod.ts`'s `production: true` flag to decide the style file to use

  - `styleUrls: [ environment.prod ? 'my.component.precompiled.scss' : 'my.component.scss' ],`
  - Gotta remember this for all new components
- Change the tailwind compile to output to the same scss file

  - Less moving parts - I liked the separate file so I'd realize quickly if it were accidentally ran/committed

3. Add CI precompile command to `package.json`

   - `"build:ci": "node --require ts-node/register projects/my-lib/src/precompile.ts && npm run build:my-lib"`

     - Very rough implementation - remove `--require ts-node/register` if converted to javascript

I use NX workspace, so I added a new target in the library's `project.json`:

```json
"ci": {
  "executor": "nx:run-commands",
  "options": {
    "command": "node --require ts-node/register libs/my-lib/src/precompile.ts"
  }
},
```

and added a the `package.json` entry as:

```json
"build": "nx run-many --all --target build",
"build:ci": "npx nx ci && npm run build",
```

allowing `build` to still be used locally.

4. Build and Package/Release as normal

   - With `@apply`'s resolved, all should flow well
   - If you used tailwind utility classes in HTML, be sure to see the very beginning of this answer

---

#### Tailwindless Depender

If you want applications to be able to utilize your library without them installing tailwind you could supply a stylesheet containing all the helper classes you used.

1. Create a stylesheet to contain all used utilities

**`projects/my-lib/style.scss`**

```scss
@tailwind utilities;
```

2. Add a `postbuild` to your `package.json` to produce the stylesheet, assuming you use `npm run build` to build the library.

```json
    "postbuild": "npx tailwind -c projects/my-lib/tailwind.config.js -i projects/my-lib/style.scss -o dist/my-lib/style.scss",
```

3. Direct depender projects to then include this compiled stylesheet:

```scss
@import 'my-lib/style.scss'
```

> Note tailwind does not compile SCSS into CSS - need to run through a SASS processor if you want to supply CSS.

Downside of this is all utility classes used in all components are produced, even if the depender app doesn't use them (same happens for projects using tailwind, so not so bad).
Also the depender project may produce duplicate utility classes if using tailwind itself.

Plus side is your library doesn't require the depender to have tailwind.

> Note that you still need the above process to resolve `@apply`'s - this only gathers the utility classes used in the HTML

Comment: I think this is by far, the cleanest "hacky" way of making TailwindCSS work with Angular libraries, the downside being that if it's a UI components library, as the library grows, so does the amount of unused CSS, when imported to any project, basically circumventing the idea of tree-shaking CSS from the project.

Comment: Agreed, but I'd assume the utility classes being used for components would 80%+ overlap with the application's uses. But using tailwind in general has the same down-side that all utilities are compiled into your front-loaded CSS, even if those parts of the app go un-accessed.

Comment: Thanks @Charly, that solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, @Charly.
Just a question, why it does not work with `@apply` ? Which is the reason? And did you find in the last months a workaround also for this?

Comment: @ptesser Sorry for the delay - the `@apply` doesn't work when packaged as a library. From what I can tell, these are resolved then ran through SCSS compilation - the compiled `.mjs` files are expected to be compiled to CSS already and are not resolved. I played around with various way but never came up with a good solution. I did however come up with another solution that may fit your needs - updating this answer shortly.

Answer (score 3):

**It's actually very easy, no need for precompiler hacks**

Got this solution from the [Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production), which suggest using the `npx tailwind` build tool (instead of`npx tailwindcss-cli`, like other solutions on the Internet suggest).

### Step 1

In your library folder, have the Tailwind config `content` as if the origin is the base project folder:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './projects/my-lib/**/*.{html,ts,css,scss}',
    './**/*.{html,ts,css,scss}',
  ],
};
```

### Step 2

In step 3, a `tailwind.scss` file will be generated into the `my-lib/src/lib` folder, so (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67719065/11438282)) you have to *include the `tailwind.scss` file in your component:*

*`styleUrls: ['../tailwind.scss']`.*

*(Careful with the path)*

### Step 3

Run this command

```bash
npx tailwindcss@latest -c ./projects/my-lib/tailwind.config.js -o ./projects/my-lib/src/lib/tailwind.scss
```

before building the library. `package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:my-lib": "npx tailwindcss@latest -c ./projects/my-lib/tailwind.config.js -o ./projects/my-lib/src/lib/tailwind.scss & ng build my-lib"
  }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work, and leaves you with an unscoped stylesheet that contains a lot more styles than required

Comment: @btx it's kind of weird that everyone has their own working solution. this is what works for me though, I get a 600~ line `tailwind.scss` file that only has what is used in the scope I define in the `tailwind.config.js`

Comment: This was the simplest answer in my opinion. Minimal tailwind.scss file. I pointed to my tailwind.config.js living in the root of my project for the tailwind command. Works well.

Comment: @Tovar if you ship your library to npm, you will be required to bundle `@tailwind-base` in your library, to make sure your component is properly redered. And Tailwind does not support scoping the base styles. Other people might use `normalize.css` or equal and not tailwind base. Thats why my solution is slightly different from yours.

Comment: @btx in my solution, Tailwind (specifically, the `npx tailwind` CLI tool) is only used in build, meaning it is only a dev dependency since only the build result should be published to NPM (according to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#publishing-your-library))

Comment: @Tovar yes, but your components will not work in non-tailwind projects, since they are missing the CSS-reset from Tailwind, so the layout might be broken.

Comment: @btx oh I didn't know that! I'll have to be careful then, thanks for the knowledge

Answer (score 2):

### Simplest solution that's proved working with Angular 16 (2023)

It works for HTML classes aswell as `@apply`.

Create another `tailwind.config.js` in your library root, e.g. `./projects/ngx-lib/tailwind.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
   content: ['./projects/ngx-lib/src/**/*.{html,ts}'],
};
```

> **The problem is, that we can not scope all Tailwind base-styles out of the box, so we need to fix this.**

Create `projects/ngx-tib/src/theme/tailwind-setup.scss` and put in

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Also create `projects/ngx-tib/src/theme/tailwind.scss`.

In your `lib.component.scss`, add:

```
ngx-lib {
   @import "../theme/tailwind";
}
```

In your package json, add this script and always run it before building the library:

```
"build:lib": "npm run build:lib:tailwind && ng build ngx-lib",
"build:lib:tailwind": "tailwind -c projects/ngx-lib/tailwind.config.js -i projects/ngx-lib/src/theme/tailwind-setup.scss -o projects/ngx-lib/src/theme/tailwind.scss",
```

In the end, the SCSS compiler will do the prefixing for us.

#### Development:

If you are importing the library to your demo app during development, you will need to add the library paths to the root project's `tailwind.config.js`:

```
content: [
   './src/**/*.{html,ts}',
   './projects/ngx-lib/src/**/*.{html,ts}'
],
```

Comment: If the project that's using the package overrides a default Tailwind color, and the library being imported uses that color, will the library component have this new color or the Tailwind default?

Comment: @Evanss good point. Since Tailwind does not use CSS variables for it's color palette, it will keep the default colors unfortunately. You can check my repository if you like to try it yourself: https://github.com/btxtiger/angular-library-skeleton
You can switch between dist and local component in app.module.ts